# node sequelize one-to-many mapping belongsTo table with unique email constraint

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create report with custom `unique` id and I want user to request `full report` by passing email id. so I have 1 reports table and 1 emails table. I want to restrict 1 email per report (same email can be used for another report). please refer the below models.

**REPORT**

```
sequelize.define("report", {
  report_id: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  word_count: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT
  },
  document_type: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  status: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
})
```

**EMAIL**

```
sequelize.define("report_email", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  email_acknowledgement_id: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  full_report_link: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
})
```

**MAPPING**

```
db.Reports.hasMany(ReportEmails, { foreignKey: 'reportId' });
db.ReportEmails.belongsTo(Reports, { foreignKey: 'reportId' });
```

In `emails` table I am getting `reportId` column with `null` value. I am new to database concepts and `sequelize`, please any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to appropriately set up the associations. One report may have numerous linked emails thanks to the one-to-many relationship you created in the given code. But it appears that the foreign key references could be problematic.

When defining associations in Sequelize, you must make sure that the foreign key supplied corresponds to the actual column name in your table. To match the primary key of the `Report` database, the foreign key in your example should be `report_id` in the `Email` table. To fix this, use the functions `Report.hasMany(Email, {foreignKey:'report_id'})` and `Email.belongsTo(Report, {foreignKey:'report_id'})`.

When these associations are properly set, Sequelize will take care of the connections between reports and emails, enabling you to link emails to certain reports and quickly obtain the information connected with those reports. This should fix the problem where the `reportId` field in the `Email` database contained null values, making sure that each email is connected to a report as intended.